# AWS CodeBuild plugin fails to find the codebuild project with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-codebuild

So, I was trying to run my Jenkins builds on codebuild using the AWS CodeBuild plugin. With a freestyle job, I filled in the details and it worked fine.

However, when I tried it with Jenkins pipeline, it fails to find the codebuild project.

Pipeline:

```
steps {
    withAWS(credentials: "AWS_ID", region: "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION") {
        sh 'aws codebuild list-projects'
        awsCodeBuild credentialsId: "CodeBuild_AWS_ID",
            credentialsType: "jenkins", 
            projectName: 'newCodeBuildProject', 
            region: "us-west-2", 
            sourceControlType: "project", 
            sourceLocationOverride: "https://github.com/me/myrepo", 
            sourceTypeOverride: "GITHUB", 
            sourceVersion: "mybranch"
}
```

Console Output:

```
12:38:50  Constructing AWS CredentialsSetting AWS region eu-west-2 
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh

12:38:51  + aws codebuild list-projects

12:38:53  {
12:38:53      "projects": [
12:38:53          "newCodeBuildProject"
12:38:53      ]
12:38:53  }
[Pipeline] awsCodeBuild
12:38:53  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] Using given AWS access and secret key for authorization (provided from Jenkins credentials CodeBuild_AWS_ID)
12:38:54  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] Project newCodeBuildProject does not exist.
```

and it threw the error below in the console:

```
CodeBuildException
    at CodeBuildStep$CodeBuildExecution.run(CodeBuildStep.java:624)
    at CodeBuildStep$CodeBuildExecution.run(CodeBuildStep.java:578)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

There was a similar issue last year but it says its fixed. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codebuild-jenkins-plugin/issues/66

Comment: Can you confirm the Region and Project Name is correct under Project Configuration. Seems the Plugin cannot see the project in response.

Comment: so, the Region and Project name is coming from the Jenkinsfile and not from the Project Configuration. we can confirm the region is same from my code blocks above, the project does return on running `aws codebuild list-projects` which can be confirmed in the 'console output:' above.

Answer (score 0):

so you're doing an assume role using `withAWS` but then your specifying codebuild plugin to use the same creds from jenkins credential store (that you used to perform the assume role). We need to use the creds we acquired when the assume role is successful instead.

Therefore, we'll direct codebuild to use specific keys, that withAWS provides as env.VARS

```
steps {
    withAWS(credentials: "AWS_ID", region: "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION") {
        sh 'aws codebuild list-projects'
        awsCodeBuild credentialsType: 'keys',
            awsAccessKey: env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            awsSecretKey: env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
            projectName: 'newCodeBuildProject', 
            region: "us-west-2", 
            sourceControlType: "project", 
            sourceLocationOverride: "https://github.com/me/myrepo", 
            sourceTypeOverride: "GITHUB", 
            sourceVersion: "mybranch"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working config. Works when Jenkins passes CodeBuildWithJenkinsServiceRole role to Codebuild:

```
withAWS(region: 'ap-southeast-2', role: 'CodeBuildWithJenkinsServiceRole', 
 roleAccount: '123456789123', externalId: '123-2c1a-4367-aa09-123') {
 awsCodeBuild projectName: 'Project1',
 sourceControlType: 'project',
 credentialsType: 'keys',
 awsAccessKey: env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
 awsSecretKey: env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
 awsSessionToken: env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
 region: 'ap-southeast-2',
 envVariables: '[ { GITHUB_OWNER, test }, { GITHUB_REPO, testrepo } ]',
 artifactTypeOverride: 'S3', 
 artifactLocationOverride: 'artifacts',
 overrideArtifactName: 'True',
 buildSpecFile: buildspec
 }
```